# WinJS Runtime Error

Tags: javascript, winjs

I am making a feed reader in Visual Studio using JavaScript, and when I run it, I get an error:

```
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference
```

and the code that is affected is:

```
articlelistElement.addEventListener("iteminvoked", itemInvoked);
```

articleListElement refers to a variable that references a WinJS.UI.Listview.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like your `articlelistElement` is `null` or `undefined`. Time to use your trusted debugger.

Comment: Clearly `articlelistElement` is `undefined`.  Where do you define it?

Comment: You may have a typo: `articlelistElement` and `articleListElement`

Comment: I define articlelistElement like this, just before the affected code.: `var articlelistElement = document.getElementById("articlelist");` Also, the articlelist is declared in the HTML file like this: `<div id="articlelist" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{ itemDataSource: C9Data.ItemList.dataSource, itemTemplate: C9ItemTemplate }"></div>`

Comment: And after using the debugger, it's null.

Answer (score 0):

If your document.getElementById("articlelist") is returning null, then you must be attempting to add the listener before the DOM is actually loaded.

If you started with the Blank project template, then in default.js you'll see this code:

```
app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
            // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
            // your application here.
        } else {
            // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
            // Restore application state here.
        }
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
    }
};
```

Until this activated event is called, the DOM won't be ready and getElementById can return null. (For a full run-down of the activation sequence, see Chapter 3 of my free ebook, [*Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript*](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2)).

If you're using the Navigation or Grid app templates, then you need to place that initialization code inside the page control's ready method (or the processed method). With the Navigation template, you'll see that code in pages/home/home.js. (The same chapter of my free ebook talks about page controls.)

That's the first step--if you're calling getElementById at the right time, then it should give you back the div where you declare the ListView.

There's more to the story, however, because to attach an event handler properly to a WinJS control, you have to make sure that control has been instantiated. This is the purpose of WinJS.UI.processAll in the Blank template code above (the same call is also made automatically as part of loading a page control).

[WinJS.UI.processAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh440975.aspx) (or [WinJS.UI.process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh440976.aspx), which works in an individual element and its children rather than the whole document), goes through the DOM looking for data-win-control attributes. When it finds one, it parses the data-win-options attribute (if you provide one), and then calls the constructor identified in data-win-control with that parsed options object.

Until that happens, the  where you declare the control will just be a div and not contain any other control structure.

With page controls, again, within the processed or ready methods the controls should be instantiated. In the Blank template, you need to attach a completed handler to WinJS.UI.processAll:

```
args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {
    //Controls have been instantiated, do initialization here

    //Note that calling .then and not .done is necessary because we need to return a promise
    //to args.setPromise.
});
```

At that point, then, document.getElementById("articlelist") should get you to the ListView's host div.

The last step is that to attach a handler to a WinJS control event, you have to add the listener to the control *object* not the host div, which you get through the .winControl property of that host element. So your code needs to look like this:

```
articlelistElement.winControl.addEventListener("iteminvoked", itemInvoked);
```